# OpenCart: Creating a standalone Ajax page

Tags: opencart

I'm working on an OpenCart project. I'm creating a "quick view" effect on the special products on the homepage where if people mouse over the item, a popover displays including a bigger image and an add to cart button.

I'm trying to create an Ajax page where I can use in my js to call and get the details of the product.

My ajax file works fine as far as looking at the passed query string and returning some data; I just don't know how I can include the opencart core files, or module files where I can use to get the details.

I hope I'm making sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and best method would be to use the framework itself and simply use the methods provided to get the data you want. You can read the basics about how to use the framework [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13484904/711273) assuming you are a php developer and have a basic grasp of OOP and MVC

Comment: Thanks Jay, I'm fairly familiar with PHP, OOP, and MVC; however, I didn't find anything Ajax-related in that guide.

Comment: You said you already have a working AJAX app. All you need to do is change your URL from the one you have now to one that uses the framework and you instantly have access to all of the built in framework objects/methods